# Java finding opened .chm files

Tags: java, chm

I have got a running process hh.exe for .chm files. I need to get the name of all the opened .chm files using java code.

Answer (score 2):

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("tasklist.exe /nh /v"); would return you the applications running and you should be able to filter out based on the file extension.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that you cannot tell if a file is open or not using pure Java code.